# If I have 2 web domains that have the same ip address, how should I test in browser for each web domain if by just typing the ip address?

Tags: networking, server, kubuntu, apache2, dns

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04 and a newbie, I have made 2 web domains: site1.com and site2.com, both of them having the same ip address, but when I type the ip address on the browser, only site1.com appears. If I want to get site2.com to appear using the same ip address, how should I do that?

Comment: Same as a postal address: You need more than merely the address. You need a Floor or Apartment or Suite or Box number, too. In computers, we use a Port for that: `ip_address:port` or ` xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy`

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways around this is to edit the `/etc/hosts` file on your local machine to point some internal network addresses to the same IP address.

For example, you can edit your `/etc/hosts` file to include these lines:

```
127.0.0.1       site1.local
127.0.0.1       site2.local
```

<sub>**Note:** Be sure to replace `127.0.0.1` with the actual IP address. For the names, you can put almost anything, but do yourself a favour and do not use the common TLDs like `.com` or `.net`. It can create confusion later.</sub>

With the `hosts` file updated, you can now edit your Apache config files for the site. For example, `site1.com` might look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin none@noaddy.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com

        ServerName site1.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Add a `ServerAlias` record that has the domain name you created in `/etc/hosts`. Generally, I write this to the line immediately after `ServerName` so that it looks something like:

```
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias site1.com site1.local
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Save the file, then restart (or reload) Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then you can go to your browser and access the sites using `site1.local` and `site2.local` (or whatever you assigned).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have used your suggestion but I am only able to let site2.com view by using its aliases and domain name, but not the ip address, in fact, it only leads me to site1.com when I type the ip address in the browser (both site1.com and site2.com has the same ip address)

Comment: You don’t need to use IP addresses in the browser with the solution offered. This lets you use an internal-only domain name 

Comment: Ah I see, thanks~